# Native rsync protocol security

Tags: cryptography, network, encryption, protocols

Is the native rsync protocol (port 873) secure? Does it encrypt data or credentials?

I'm planning on using rsync to store encrypted files in the cloud, I'm wondering whatever the password is transferred in clear.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The native rsync protocol does not encrypt anything. It is meant only for trusted networks.

To use rsync in a secure way, use it with SSH (see the "`-e`" command-line option) or over a VPN.